# Can I code a whole Flutter app with just VS Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

I'm just starting to program with Flutter and I'm wondering if it's possible to program a whole flutter app, with just VS Code, because of many reasons I can't use Android Studio on my laptop.

Just knowing if it's possible would be enough for me.

Well, I started a standard Flutter App and I'm developing it from the basis.

Comment: Adding on the what @Gwhyyy mentioned, just be aware that as you start developing and getting into the details you might need to configure certain things within Android studio and/or Xcode for iOS. These generally tend to be platform specific configurations. E.g. if your app needs to get the user's location, use Firestore db etc. but of these are well documented so you should be okay. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can code a whole Flutter project with VScode, you need just to follow the install process of all requirements for flutter:

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

However, you will need Android Studio in order to get an Android Emulator, to debug and preview your work process. ( you will not need to run it every time from Android Studio)

and when you will have the emulator installed then you can do the whole code process of a Flutter project only from VScode